# Rudolff's symbol for unknown

Tags: math-history

I have read Florian Cajori's book "A history of mathematical notations."

Cajori explained about several symbols for unknown. Rudolff used weird symbols.

[image]

I could identify some symbols: "z" for zensus, "c" with a loop for cubus, "eszett ß" for sursolidum.

But, I could not understand the symbol for radix. It looks like conjunction of "2" and "e".

Could you teach me which letter was used for radix?

Comment: I think it's an "rx". If you look at some older [German](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BCtterlinschrift) [scripts](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Kurrentschrift) for handwriting, the end of it looks very much like a lower case $x$, and the beginning is consistent with being a handwritten $r$. And of course, "rx" as an abbreviation for "radix" makes some sense.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your kind comments!